# Laravel if one of the fields is not set, laravel throws error

Tags: laravel-5

I have very big problem.
When I submit my form with data everything goes well, but when I won't fill one field in my form laravel throw error **MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218**
I have validation in my controller but it does not change anything. When the form is empty it throws an error.
Somebody has a solution for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route for this form post use veriables as optional. Use ? In your route definition.

```
/{var?}/{var2?}/......
```

From laravel docs-

Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter, but make the presence of that route parameter optional. You may do so by placing a ? mark after the parameter name. Make sure to give the route's corresponding variable a default value:

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});

Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = 'John') {
    return $name;
});
```

**or**

```
// validate the info, create rules for the inputs

$rules = array('data_rozpoczecia' => 'required', 'data_zakonczenia' => 'required');

    // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form 
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules); 

    if ($validator->fails()) { return redirect()->back(); } else{ //do what you want. }
```

Comment: I will try on Mondat and tell if it works thanks for your reply. Ten you will get the Best answer!

Comment: It is still the same problem. I have made something like that: `Route::post('/absenceslook/post/{data_rozpoczecia?}/{data_zakonczenia?}/', [...`

Comment: `Route::post('/absenceslook/post/{data_rozpoczecia?}/{data_zakonczenia?}/', [
    'uses' => 'AbsencesController@postAbsencesLook',
    'as' => 'post.absences.look',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);`

Comment: please remove / at the end of route from above and plz show postAbsencesLook() function code and view code where your form html is here.

Comment: I removed it and it does not change nothing. `public function postAbsencesLook(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
      'data_rozpoczecia' => 'required',
      'data_zakonczenia' => 'required',
      ]);
      ...
      ...
      return view('parent.lookabsences')->with([
        'absences' =>$absences,
        'grupa' => '',
        'kids' => $kids,
        'dziecko' => '',
        'id_school' => self::getSchoolId()
      ]);
  }`

Comment: the problem is you have set these required.

[ 'data_rozpoczecia' => 'required', 'data_zakonczenia' => 'required', ]

Comment: Okay I deleted it but now I have got sql error. How to make thing like if these fields are empty redirect back? If I do something like that: `      if($request['data_rozpoczecia'] === '' && $request['data_zakonczenia'] === '') {
        return redirect()->back();
      }` I have got the same error.

Comment: use like this   **if(isset($request['data_rozpoczecia']) && !empty($request['data_rozpoczecia']) && isset($request['data_zakonczenia']) && !empty($request['data_zakonczenia']) ){ // do what you want } else {  return redirect()->back(); }**

Comment: I've tried your solution but still the same effect. I don't know why it throws that error. Anyway thanks for your help and time.